# QuickSort works slow for low range data

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, quicksort

lately im comparing different types of sort algorithms in python. I noticed that my quicksort isnt handling well inputs where values are repeated.

```
def compare_asc(a, b):
    return a <= b


def partition(a, p, r, compare):
    pivot = a[r]
    i = p-1
    for j in range(p, r):
        if compare(a[j], pivot):
            i += 1
            a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    a[i+1], a[r] = a[r], a[i+1]
    return i + 1


def part_quick_sort(a, p, r, compare):
    if p < r:
        q = partition(a, p, r, compare)
        part_quick_sort(a, p, q-1, compare)
        part_quick_sort(a, q+1, r, compare)


def quick_sort(a, compare):
    part_quick_sort(a, 0, len(a)-1, compare)
    return a
```

Then I test this

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import sys

test_list1 = np.random.randint(-10000, 10000, size=10000).tolist()
start = timer()
test_list1 = quick_sort(test_list1, compare_asc)
elapsed = timer() - start
print(elapsed)

test_list2 = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10000).tolist()
start = timer()
test_list2 = quick_sort(test_list2, compare_asc)
elapsed = timer() - start
print(elapsed)
```

In this example i get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`, so i added `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)` and after that i get this output:

```
0.030029324000224733
5.489867554000284
```

Can anyone explain why it throws this recursion depth error only during sorting 2nd list ? And why there it is such big time difference ?

Comment: wild guess: would `p<=r` in the first line of `part_quick_sort` help?

Comment: No, still the same :/

Comment: How about switching the second line to `<`? Looks like the `<=` makes you switch out equal elements (although they are already in the correct order).

Comment: it gives 2.5s - still much longer than in 1st case. And still without  `sys.setrecursionlimit(1000000)` `RecursionError` pops out

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint:  pass a list where all the elements are the same, and watch what it does line by line.  It will take time quadratic in the number of elements, and recurse to a level approximately equal to the number of elements.

The usual quicksort partition implementations proceed from both ends, so that in the all-equal case the list slice is approximately cut in half.  You can get decent performance in this case for your "only look left-to-right" approach, but the clearest way to do so is to partition into *three* regions:  "less than", "equal", and "greater than".

That can be done in a single left-to-right pass, and is usually called the "[Dutch national flag problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem)".  As the text on the linked page says,

> The solution to this problem is of interest for designing sorting algorithms; in particular, variants of the quicksort algorithm that must be robust to repeated elements need a three-way partitioning function ...

### CODE

For concreteness, here's a complete implementation doing one-pass "left to right" single-pivot 3-way partitioning.  It also incorporates other well-known changes needed to make a quicksort robust for production use.  Note:

- You cannot create a pure quicksort that avoids worst-case quadratic time.  The best you can do is average-case `O(N*log(N))` time, and (as below, for one way) make worst-case `O(N**2)` time unlikely.
- You can (as below) guarantee worst-case logarithmic recursion depth.
- In this approach, a list of all-equal elements is not a bad case, but a very *good* case:  the partitioning routine is called just once total.

The code:

```
from random import randrange

def partition(a, lo, hi, pivot):
    i = L = lo
    R = hi
    # invariants:
    # a[lo:L]  < pivot
    # a[L:i]  == pivot
    # a[i:R]     unknown
    # a[R:hi]  > pivot
    while i < R:
        elt = a[i]
        if elt < pivot:
            a[L], a[i] = elt, a[L]
            L += 1
            i += 1
        elif elt > pivot:
            R -= 1
            a[R], a[i] = elt, a[R]
        else:
            i += 1
    return L, R

def qsort(a, lo=0, hi=None):
    if hi is None:
        hi = len(a)

    while True:   # sort a[lo:hi] in place
        if hi - lo <= 1:
            return

        # select pivot ar random; else it's easy to construct
        # inputs that systematically require quadratic time
        L, R = partition(a, lo, hi, a[randrange(lo, hi)])

        # must recur on only the shorter chunk to guarantee
        # worst-case recursion depth is logarithmic in hi-lo
        if L - lo <= hi - R:
            qsort(a, lo, L)
            # loop to do qsort(a, R, hi)
            lo = R
        else:
            qsort(a, R, hi)
            # loop to do qsort(a, lo, L)
            hi = L
```

Comment: Dual Pivot version is my next target, but first i wanted to implement this one. I checked list full of the same elements and i noticed that partition always slices just one element. Also I see that `a[i+1], a[r] = a[r], a[i+1]` does a lot of swaps even when elements are the same. Do i understand correctly that without changing it to dualpivot i cant do anything about 1st one ? But can i eliminate somehow swaping of the same elements ?

Comment: My answer had nothing to do with "Dual Pivot".  The solution to the Dutch national flag (DNF) problem is a single-pivot algorithm, very much like what you already have, but creating three regions instead of two.  Dual Pivot algorithms create at least 3 regions, and possibly 5.  Please don't proceed without doing the work to understand DNF first:  it's a basic technique for a fundamental problem, and you'll just fall into the same confusions over and over until you do understand it :-)